# Accessing nested XML node using path stored as text in MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, xml, phpmyadmin

I'm parsing multiple XML files. The paths to the desired nodes have been stored in my MySQL database for easy access.

Paths that aren't nested don't give a problem. But when I store a path like 'fields->sub_category' there seems to be a problem with the '->' selector. When I literally write the path in the code it works, but when I retrieve the string from the database and use it as variable, it fails to work. Why can't I use this syntax as a variable when it's coming from the database?

With phpmyadmin i've tried changing the index properties from varchar to text, changing the collation etc, but to no avail.

I've also tried to store the path like 'category subcategory' without the '->' and adding it in between using str_replace. This also doesn't work.

```
$nodes = $connect->prepare("SELECT * FROM table");
$nodes->execute();
$node = $nodes->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$title_node = $node['title']; //value is 'name'
$category_node = $node['subcategory']; //value is 'fields->sub_category'

$feedlink = "http://link.to.myfeed.com/feed.xml";
$x = new XMLReader;
$doc = new DOMDocument;  
$x->open($feedLink);

while ($x->read() && $x->name !== 'product');
while ($x->name == 'product') {

$p = simplexml_import_dom($doc->importNode($x->expand(), true));
echo $p->$title_node; // Actually returns all the titles found
echo $p->$category_node; // Does absolutely nothing
}
```

I expected the

```
echo $p->$category_node;
```

would return the actual data within that node, but instead the path is not found. What is going on with the string that contains the special characters '->'?

Here's a reduced version of the XML structure:

```
<product>
<name>Productname</name>
<price>99.99</price>
<fields>
    <categories>Main category data</categories>
    <color>Black</color>
    <sub_category>Sub category data</sub_category>
</fields>
</product>
```

Comment: I've added the basic structure. I don't think it'll make much difference since 'hardcoding' the path to the node works fine, but retrieving the path from the db and assigning it to a variable doesn't.

Comment: At the beginning of the code `$title_node = $node['title']; //value is 'name' `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SimpleXML, you can't use it as you would like...

```
$category_node = $node['subcategory']; //value is 'fields->sub_category'
```

As you mentioned later on it's because of the `->` in the name and this is a limit of SimpleXML that each element must be separate.

To get round this, you can use a short method to do this for you, it splits the node name into it's components (using `explode()`) and then loops over each one changing the node for each level...

```
function getNode( $node, $path )    {
    foreach ( explode("->", $path) as $step ) {
        $node = $node->$step;
    }
    return $node;
}
```

So instead of

```
echo $p->$category_node; // Does absolutely nothing
```

use...

```
echo getNode($p, $category_node);
```